# Permission displayName with brackets in ABP

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using AspNet Boilerplate and I don't know why when add new permission in querys the displayName comes with brackets.

[Problem image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSVbg.png)

[Permission creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZDz7.png)

Role and User permission comes normal without brackets.

Note: My english is not very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed the translation in your localization file, as mentioned on https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization#server-side:

> If a given string is not defined anywhere, then it returns the given string by humanizing and wrapping it with `[` and `]` by default (instead of throwing an Exception). Example: If a given text is "ThisIsMyText", then the result will be "[This is my text]"

Edit your translation file and add the new translation key you want to use.

Comment: I understand it by reading the documentation, thanks for your  help!